# Virtualhosts not resolve for Apache

Tags: apache-virtualhost

I have a website in /var/www/statgenerique5. I have added the following to the  /etc/apache2/sites-available/statgen5.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName statgen5.local

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/statgenerique5

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I restart and reload Apache service, but it's impossible to ping or access to statgen5.local.

I also configure /etc/hosts file with my ip and statgen5.local but it's not working.

I'm using Debian 8.6

What's wrong ?

Comment: Related: [Can not resolve .local domains internal to my office LAN](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/457525)

Comment: Also related (to to the special mDNS domain `.local`): [How do devices add DNS entries on a local network?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/175963)

Answer (score 0):

The config must be present/symlinked in the `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` directory.

Typically you would

```
cd /etc/apache2/sites-enabled
ln -s ../sites-available/statgen5.conf
```

and restart the server.